# Flask - Multiprocessing (RuntimeError: Working outside of request context)

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a Process that calls a function in Flask.

Here's my code:

Here are my imports:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Pool

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request, flash, Markup, make_response, Response`

def getCookie(getState):
    while True:
        if getState.value == 1:
           return request.cookies.get('username')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processValues = Value('i', 1)
    p = Process(target=getCookie, args=(processValues,))
    p.start()
    app.run()
    p.join()
```

But it throws me an Runtime Error. I know this is because my other process `getCookie` cant run the function `request.cookies.get()` from flask.

I'm not sure how to fix this because all the explanations out there are quite .... Intense haha. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: when program uses `threading` then threads share memory with data and they have access to all values - ie. `request`. When program uses `multiprocessing` then every process runs in separated memory and it has no access to values and you have to send all data (ie. `request`) to process.

Comment: @Denise explanation: you run a new process and he(process) doesn't know anything about `request` / `response` / `cookies` / `headers` etc.

Comment: @furas so I should use multithreading instead ?

Comment: if you want to get cookie then you have to send it to process as argument. `args=(processValues, request.cookies.get('username'))` and get it `def getCookie(getState, username):`

Comment: @furas could u put it as an answer and the full edited code? so i can tick as an answer

Comment: I can't put it as answer because question is closed as duplicated. And I can't reopen it.

Comment: @furas Well thanks! ur answer really helped. And PS.. I don't see how this question is a duplicate. The other question that was suppose to be a duplicated of mine isn't even close to being my problem.

Comment: see `Manually Push a Context` in [The Request Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/) and in [The Application Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/). Maybe it helps to explain why it can be dupicated. It shows how to access `request` and `app` outside main thread. But sending `request` or `cookies` as argument can be more readable.

Comment: @furas I have posted another question. Could u go there and give the answer?